# Does refreshing Dev FF reset regular FF too?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-edition

After refreshing Developer Edition for the first time, normal FF looks like it was just installed.  Including the usual things that get wiped in a refresh (extensions, themes, settings, etc.), all my bookmarks, histories, saved logins and such are gone too.  I came up empty after some googling, so is this normal behavior?

Comment: That depends: were you using the same profiles in both or different ones? If you were using the same profile, than that's the expected behavior. If not, then it's unexpected!

Comment: I don't have a firefox profile.  It would make sense if there was a default profile of sorts if you haven't set one up.

Comment: Firefox uses the `default` profile, Dev Edition uses the `dev-edition-default` profile. Unless you changed this manually, of course. Would you mind filing a bug in [this component](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=Toolkit&component=Startup%20and%20Profile%20System&resolution=---)?